# Test if a row of a matrix equals a given vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector

How to construct a function that evaluates if any line of matrix `mat` is equal to vector `vec` in code below:

```
set.seed(000)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(20),4,5)
vec <- c(1.3297993, -0.9285670,  0.7635935, -0.2992151,  0.4356833)
mat[3,]
vec
mat==vec
```

Also, how determine if at least one `vec` value is in `mat`?

Note: `mat == vec` should be equal to `TRUE`, ie `mat-vec == 0` if `mat-vec <tol`, where `tol = 1e-5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your example won't work because of the [floating point trap](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) (starting on page 9).

This should do the trick:

```
set.seed(000)
mat <- round(matrix(rnorm(20),4,5), digits = 7)
vec <- c(1.3297993, -0.9285670,  0.7635935, -0.2992151,  0.4356833)
```

Now, `mat[3, ] == vec` is true.

If you want to know if one row of `mat` matches `vec`, try:

```
apply(mat, 1, function(x) identical(x, vec))
```

To find out if at least one value of `vec` is in `mat`, you can do:

```
length(vec[which(vec %in% mat)])
```

The result reflects the number of matches found between your vector and your matrix.

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work? Just rechecked it, works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
compare <- function(mat, vec, tol=1e-5)
{
    ok <- apply(mat, 1, function(v) {
        all(abs(v - vec) < tol)
    })
    any(ok)
}


v <- 1:5
m <- matrix(rnorm(25), nrow=5)
compare(m, v)
# FALSE

m[1,] <- v
compare(m, v)
# TRUE
```